# Unable to launch spyder

Tags: spyder

I get this error when I launch Spyder through cmd
Also, I can't run it by clicking the shortcut

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Akash Shanmugaraj\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from spyder.app.start import main
  File "C:\Akash Shanmugaraj\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 22, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "C:\Users\Akash Shanmugaraj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\Akash Shanmugaraj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Akash Shanmugaraj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Akash Shanmugaraj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\Akash Shanmugaraj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\Akash Shanmugaraj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Akash Shanmugaraj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)
```

Comment: I recommend removing and reinstalling Anaconda

Comment: Recommend you to install anaconda again with default settings.

Comment: @Sourav I tried reinstalling it but same error comes

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. "activate base" didn't help, but just found a solution. Certainly not quite correct, but it works.
Go to folder:
C:\Users\<*your_login*>\AppData\Roaming\Python
and rename it ("Python") on "Python_x" or something else.
Spyder and Navigator starts up and so far everything works, but don't delete that folder.

Answer (score 0):

In cmd try activating the base environment(or any other relevant environment) by running

```
activate base
```

and then try running spyder.

Comment: Still no avail @VedAgr

Comment: @Akash_Lezend - But did you make sure that base is your environment?
If it is not.. then activate the relevant environment.